# How to redirect any url that do not match any @RequestMapping parameter in the application

Tags: spring, web.xml

I use Spring MVC in my web application. I am trying to redirect any url that match the pattern `http://localhost:8080/my-app/*` to a specific controller. But if the url is something like the following, `http://localhost:8080/my-app/test` and if there is a controller as follows:

@Controller
    @RequestMapping("test")
    public class TestClass
    {

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/landing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String selectHomePage(ModelMap model)
        {
        //do something
        }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listFaqCollections(@ModelAttribute("ownedby") String ownedBy, ModelMap model)
    {
    //do something
    }
}
```

And I have another class as follows:

```
@Controller
    public class InvalidUrslRedirect
    {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String redirectInvalidUrls(Model model)
    { 
        //do something 
    }
```

All the urls that are invalid will be redirected to the above controller class.

The valid urls would be as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app/test/landing
http://localhost:8080/my-app/test/list?ownedby=me
```

But if the url is something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app/test/list?ownedbys=me
```

the normal tomcat 404  error page is displayed and the it is not getting redirected to the `InvalidUrslRedirect` class

In my `web.xml` file, I have the following:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/core/root-context.xml, classpath:spring/core/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

In the `spring-security.xml`, I have:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
```

I have been searching the net for some time now, but could not find much help. is there any way i can achieve such a functionality. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you want to redirect every request other than e.g. "/test". In this case you'll need two methods:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectEverythingOtherThanTest(){
return "redirect:/pageToRedirectTo.html"
}

@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testRequest(){
//some stuff
return "somepage.html";
}
```

Also remember about @Controller annotation on your class.

Comment: I think you have not understood me correctly, all the urls that have a valid path should go to the correct methods, and the invalid urls starting with the pattern as http://localhost:8080/my-app/ should go to a different controller class

Comment: In my example everything that isn't mapped explicitly (like "/test") will enter the controller method redirectEverythingOtherThanTest. If you have any method with explicit mapping ("/test" , "/whatever" etc), your request will reach that method. So: localhost:8080/my-app/wrongUrl will go to  redirectEverythingOtherThanTest() , localhost:8080/my-app/test will go to testRequest()

Comment: thanks for the update, but I am trying to implement an entirely new class for the wrong urls

Comment: `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectEverythingOtherThanTest(){
return "redirect:/pageToRedirectTo.html"
}`

just put this code in another class with @Controller annotation

Comment: Wcislo, this solution do not work for methods with parameters if a parameter name is invalid. The 404 page gets displayed in that case. eg: If my method is as follows: public String test(int param1, String param2); and if the url is: http://localhost:8080/my-app/test?param1=1&params2=test. here the second parameter is different. Is there anythin to manage such cases

Comment: You must show how your controller method looks like - better create another thread, or edit your original post

Comment: Wcislo, is there any way we can exclude urls that end with .css or .js etc from getting redirected here?

Answer (score 1):

How is your web application setup?  Which URLs is Spring looking for?  Do you have an AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer?

```
public class WebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

/**
 * Configure Spring MVC to handle ALL requests
 */
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    ....
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    ....
}

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {  
    ...
}
}
```

Comment: I do not have a AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer, and I have edited the  questions to provide more details from the web.xml file and the spring-security.xml file

Comment: Try @RequestMapping("/test") (note the "/")